# Why does gravity script pull objects so fast then slows, not constant

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

How do I get a constant speed for this gravity script. The objects start off so fast then slows down as near the target. I just want a constant speed but I thought I was achieving it.

```
private Rigidbody ownBody;
private float maxVelocityOfInfluence = 10.2f;
private float rangeOfInfluence = 20000.0f;
public bool allowRangeGizmo = false;

private void OnEnable()
{
    ownBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Collider[] cols = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, rangeOfInfluence);
    List<Rigidbody> rbs = new List<Rigidbody>();

    foreach (Collider c in cols)
    {
        Rigidbody otherBody = c.attachedRigidbody;
        if (otherBody != null && otherBody != ownBody && !rbs.Contains(otherBody) && (otherBody.transform.gameObject.tag == "Enemy1" || otherBody.transform.gameObject.tag == "Enemy2" || otherBody.transform.gameObject.tag == "Enemy3" || otherBody.transform.gameObject.tag == "Enemy4"))
        {
            rbs.Add(otherBody);

            Vector3 offset = transform.position - c.transform.position;
            otherBody.AddForce(offset * ownBody.mass);

            //  Control speed of Enemy
            if (otherBody.velocity.magnitude > maxVelocityOfInfluence)
            {
                otherBody.velocity = otherBody.velocity.normalized * maxVelocityOfInfluence;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could it be this code? It seems the offset changes the speed?

```
Vector3 offset = transform.position - c.transform.position;
otherBody.AddForce(offset * ownBody.mass);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the offset value is greater the further your are so the force added will be greater. You can normalize the offset vector so its a direction vector instead (offset.normalized * ownBody.mass).

Comment: even with this it is still increasing in speed. `ownBody.mass` = 1f and so is the enemy. Still being increased by 1+ per second. It is basically the opposite now.

Comment: otherBody.AddForce(offset * ownBody.mass); Rigidbody.AddForce will add extra force everytime its called. You can set the vecolity directly with rigidbody.velocity =  (offset.normalized * ownBody.mass); but it will override any new velocity gained from other physics interaction.

Comment: and by changing ownBody.mass to a float you can control the exact velocity you want. Thanks!